# Python AttributeError AsObj' object has no attribute with external API

Tags: python, api, flask

I am currently trying to build my first flask website.

I use this API to get movie data for the site:
https://github.com/AnthonyBloomer/tmdbv3api

When I call the API to get for example movie details:

```
from tmdbv3api import TMDb, Movie

tmdb = TMDb()
tmdb.api_key = XXX

# Define objects
movie = Movie()
def getmovie(movieid):
    film = movie.details(movieid)
    return film
```

It works perfectly I pass for example a list of movie objects to jinja and then loop through and access the details, e.g.

```
{% for movie in movies %}
        <div class="card content" style="width: 10rem;">

            <div class="content-overlay"></div>
            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex justify-content-end">
                <form action="/deletefromlist" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="movieid" value="{{ movie.id }}" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                        <span class="material-icons">
                            remove
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
                <span class="content-title">{{ movie.title }}</span>
            </div>

            <img class="content-image" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/{{ movie.poster_path }}"
                onerror="this.src='/static/imgs/default.png'" class="card-img" alt="{{ movie.title }}" />
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            Such empty. Try adding some movies.
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

This works pretty well.

**But** i also want to store data from the movie objects in a database, so that I don't have to access the API all the time:

(This tries to store a movie in the db (SQLite3) everytime it gets added by a user):

```
# Query db for watchlist, call API, then returns list of movie objects
def save_movie(movie_id):
m = movie.details(movie_id)

# check if already there
if db.execute("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE movie_id = :movie_id", movie_id=movie_id):
    return False

genre_1 = m.genres[0]["name"]
genre_2 = m.genres[1]["name"]
db.execute("INSERT INTO movies (movie_id, title, year, releasedate, running_time, imdb_id, status, overview, country, poster_path, genre_1, genre_2) VALUES (:movie_id, :title, :year, :releasedate, :running_time, :imdb_id, :status, :overview, :country, :poster_path, :genre_1, :genre_2)",
           movie_id=movie_id, title=m.title, year=m.release_date, releasedate=m.release_date, running_time=m.runtime, imdb_id=m.imdb_id, status=m.status, overview=m.overview, country=m.productioncountries, poster_path=m.poster_path, genre_1=genre_1, genre_2=genre_2)
return True
```

The problem is, no matter which attribute of the movie object I try to access it gives me the following error, e.g. if I try to get m.year:

```
AttributeError: 'AsObj' object has no attribute 'overview'
```

I tried googleing but didn't find an answer. I just don't get why jinja has no problem accessing the attributes of the movie objects. But python has.

I guess it has todo with the "creating of the attributes" at a later time?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases TMDb API is returning incomplete information when a field is empty.

You can handle this problem by using [`getattr(object, name[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) and providing a fallback value.

So instead of `overview=m.overview` you should write:

```
overview = getattr(m, 'overview', 'n/a')
```

By the way, this could also happen with other attributes. In my case it was a search result without `release_date`.